# Index to Datetime starting from a different year than 1970-1-1

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

> I am trying to transform my index to a date starting
>   from the year 2000. pd.to_datetime() only allows me to start at 1970.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"R1": [90,-92,1,5,8,11,2,2,58,3], "R2": [80,5,1,6,56,14,5,3,2,8]})
df
```

[image: date_df]

```
df.index
```

[image: date_index]

```
df_index_date_wrongoutput = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit="D")
df_index_date_wrongoutput
```

[image: date_output_wrong]

```
#desired Output
```

[image: date_desired_output]

> *# EDIT ORIGIN ERROR*

[image: origin_error]

> *# EDIT2: date_parameters*

[image: date_parameters]

Comment: Please post code only, no screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `origin` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit="D", origin='2000-01-01')
print (df)
            R1  R2
2000-01-01  90  80
2000-01-02 -92   5
2000-01-03   1   1
2000-01-04   5   6
2000-01-05   8  56
2000-01-06  11  14
2000-01-07   2   5
2000-01-08   2   3
2000-01-09  58   2
2000-01-10   3   8
```

Comment: hey, i have tried origin before, for some reason i get the following error message (see updated Question)

Comment: @DieterMueller - What is your pandas version?

Comment: @DieterMueller - do you have both parameters `unit` and `origin` ?

Comment: python: 3.7.1.final.0 & pandas: 0.23.4

Comment: I've put a screenshot with the Parameters i have available. My index was created by .reset_index

Comment: @DieterMueller - s if use both parameters `unit="D", origin='2000-01-01'` still error?

Comment: it worked! i created a new sheet and run the whole Code again. Apparently something else was faulty About my old Code. thanks for your answer :-)